# How can I maintain the position of listview when user comes back to the activity by pressing back button?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I have a `listview` and How can I maintain the position of my `ListView` in my activity when I go to another activity (by launching another intent) and then come back (press the back button)? when user click on any item in the `listview` another activity started and in that activity I have a back button when it pressed the previous `listview` activity restores its state with item position that was clicked ? I have searched but nothing useful is found and Is there any way to do that in manifest because I used below code in the `listview` activity manifest to restore its state and I know its not a good choice to restore state after orientation changes but in my case that was useful.

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: From what I understand here, when you open the new activity make sure you're not calling finish(); and then it should keep it as it was when you left the calling activity.  If you have to call finish(); then in the intent pass the value of listview.getselecteditem(); and pass it back when you recreate the original activity.

Comment: no I am not calling finish() in the listview activity

Comment: Then please add more in your post, show what you've got already.

Answer (score 1):

You could,

1. Use Intent.putExtra to pass on the selected index to the SecondActivity and then back to First.
2. Use SharedPreferences to store and retreive the index.

I could elaborate, if you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
int index = mList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = mList.getChildAt(0);
int top = (v == null) ? 0 : (v.getTop() - mList.getPaddingTop());
```

`top` gives you visible position. Then you can save it in `onSaveInstanceState()`(I don't remember exact implementation)

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
     super.onSaveInstanceState(bundle);
     bundle.putInt("tag", top);
}
```

Then restore you position in onCreate and set it to list

```
mList.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```

Answer (score 1):

kotlin way

```
val index: Int = recyclerView.scrollState
 
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(index)
```