# How to maintain scroll position of ScrollView that contains an extended ListView using FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, scrollview, expandablelistview

I have a fragment that has ScrollView containing an ExpandableHeightListView:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ExpandableHeightListView extends ListView
{
    boolean expanded = false;

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                    int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded()
    {
        return expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        if (isExpanded())
        {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                    MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
    {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }
}
```

This list view populates it's items from my firebase realtime database

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_customer_welcome, container, false);
        
        appointmentLV = (ExpandableHeightListView) view.findViewById(R.id.appointmentListView);
        ((ExpandableHeightListView) appointmentLV).setExpanded(true);
        final RelativeLayout noAppointments = view.findViewById(R.id.border);
        final LinearLayout appointments = view.findViewById(R.id.appointmentsListV);
        final String userId = Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid();
        final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Customers").child(userId).child("Appointments");
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                {
                   //show the appointments
                    appointments.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    noAppointments.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("Customers").child(userId).child("Appointments").orderByKey().startAt("2021-01-01").endAt("2021-12-31");
                    FirebaseListOptions<Appointment> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Appointment>()
                            .setLayout(R.layout.appointment_layout)
                            .setLifecycleOwner(getActivity())
                            .setQuery(query, Appointment.class)
                            .build();
                    FirebaseListAdapter<Appointment> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Appointment>(options)
                    {
                        @Override
                        protected void populateView(View v, final Appointment model, final int position)
                        {
                            // populate view
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DatabaseError error) {
                            super.onError(error);
                            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            toast.show();
                        }
                    };

                    appointmentLV.setAdapter(adapter);
                }else{
                   // don't show the appointments
                    appointments.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    noAppointments.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
            {
                //throw databaseError.toException();
                Log.d("error", databaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

The problem being, it appears that every time i go off the app, and come back to it, the scroll positions moves back to the top of the page as the list repopulates itself. How can i make it so if i go off the app and comes back, the scroll position is maintained?

[image]

Comment: You shared some code, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code.

Comment: I think the problem occurs when onCreateView is called after resuming the fragment. When the list view populates itself, it causes the scrollview to scroll back to the top of the page, instead of maintaining it's previous scroll position

Comment: The best solution I can think of is to use a [RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628449/how-can-i-maintain-the-position-of-listview-when-user-comes-back-to-the-activity).